# How to authenticate user from standalone react frontend with django backend (same domain, different ports), using a third-party CAS authentication?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, cas

I'm setting up a django backend with `Django REST framework` for providing APIs, with authentication implemented through a third-party CAS server. Currently my backend authentication has been successfully implemented (using `django-cas-ng` package), which means I can implement different permissions for different groups of user. The django backend serves through `localhost:8000` by default.

Adding a standalone react frontend (`localhost:3000` by default) seems complicating the authentication system. Requests (implemented by axios) sending from 3000 port to 8000 port are unable to authenticate.

I've tried `npm run build` to build the static files and integrate them with django. Within the same 8000 port all the authentication and permissions work fine.

Could anyone suggest how to implement authentication through different ports?

Comment: Have you tried using a token based authentication approach using something like JWT.

Comment: Hi Muljayan, is there a way to implement token based authentication with third-party CAS?@Muljayan

Comment: It depends on the third party CAS you are using. Check the documentation of the particular CAS if its not there try to add another question on stack overflow as to how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's because request sent from `localhost:3000` to `localhost:8000` doesn't contain the `sessionid` from cookies, so the user would not able to be authenticated.

For axios, setting the `withCredential` option will include HTTPOnly `sessionid`:

```
axios("example.com", {
  method: "post",
  data: someJsonData,
  withCredentials: true
})
```

For django side, the response will need to include:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true, 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS,
Access-Control-Allow-Headers Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000 
// CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN = ['*'] or CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True will not work
```

Thanks again to @xyres for providing CORS info and it really help a lot during solving this issue!

Answer (score 1):

By making cross port requests you're breaking browsers' [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). This is done for security reasons.

Browsers also allow you to get around this policy by setting up something called [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Basically, you'll have to return a header called `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from your backend to tell the browser that you trust the incoming source.

For more information, you can read the linked pages.

---

During development, I use these settings to listen to cross domain requests:

```python
# It may be a good idea to use appropriate values during production

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['*'] # if you're serving your frontend 
                             # and backend under same domain and port
                             # during production, then you can remove
                             # this.
```

Then I also have a middleware which injects the required CORS headers on every HTTP request.

This isn't required if you're serving the frontend and backend on the same domain and port. So it's a good idea not to use this middleware during production. If you must, use appropriate values.

I keep this code in a file called `middleware.py` and keep this file in the same directory as my `settings.py` file.

```
# project_name/project_name/middleware.py

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings

CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN = getattr(settings, 'CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN', '*')
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = getattr(settings, 'CORS_ALLOW_METHODS', ['POST', 'GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH'])
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = getattr(settings, 'CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS', ['content-type', 'authorization'])
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = getattr(settings, 'CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS', True)
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = getattr(settings, 'CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS', ['content-type', 'location'])

class CorsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def set_headers(self, response):
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = ','.join(CORS_ALLOW_METHODS)
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = ','.join(CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS)
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true' if CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS else 'false'
        response['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = ','.join(CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS)

        return response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response = self.set_headers(response)
        return response
```

And then finally, change some settings to tell Django to use this middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ... other middlewares ...

    'project_name.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
```

---

**Important:** You may not need any of the code from this answer in production if you're serving your frontend and backend under the same domain and port. But it is still a good idea to learn more about CORS.

Comment: Hi xyres. Many thanks for your reply! I've tried to set up a refresh frontend & backend separated system (without CAS) through your instruction to test the CORS issue. It seems that it's not the issue of CORS (because other APIs that don't need authentication work fine). Currently my test is that login at ```localhost:8000/admin/``` and user request send from ```localhost:3000``` to ```localhost:8000```. Is there anything wrong with this setting? Thanks!