# How to integrate Angular8 with Django 2.2?

Tags: python, django, angular

I am trying to integrate my Angular8 frontend app with my Django 2.2 backend.  I have only run the following command for setting up Django:

```
django-admin startproject project_name
```

Following this I moved my Angular app within the folder created.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-angular-cli/) and set up my settings.py file as shown on the site.

Here is my settings.py file.

```py
"""
Django settings for photorest project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 't1w0%3@l7!dnx_sm&xho3hdyyg4)$_p(%pz0h*^#a%9m$v2pr$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'photorest.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'photorest.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ANGULAR_APP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'photoapp/dist')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(ANGULAR_APP_DIR)
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Here is my urls.py file:

```py
"""photorest URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', serve, kwargs={'path': 'index.html', 'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT })
]
```

According to the website that should have rendered the content and display the angular frontend correctly however it does not work and the js files are also not found.  Here is the error I am getting:
[image]

I have also tried to add a templates directory with the index.html file as well importing the necessary angular js files.  I then change the index.html url above to `TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name=name)`

Here is the index.html in templates:

```html
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}">
      <!-- index.html -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'photoapp/polyfills-es2015.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'photoapp/polyfills-es5.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'photoapp/styles-es5.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'photoapp/vendor-es5.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'photoapp/runtime-es5.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'photoapp/main-es5.js' %}"></script></body>
</html>
```

And here is what this displays:
[image]

However even though it renders the css and other stuff it does not correctly reference the images located in the assets/img/ directory of Angular resulting in a 404

So when in Angular I am referencing image as `src="assets/img/img_name"` they are not rendered.

Additionally if for example I have added a redirectTo in Angular such that when someone lands on localhost:8000 it redirects to localhost:8000/dashboard.  If I retype this url or refresh the page then this results in a 404 error again because Django can't find that path.

Did someone attempt to do this and have managed to do it correctly?

Comment: I work with React and I serve frontend and backend separately. That is, Django is only responsible for responding to api requests and it doesn't serve React files. The React frontend is served by a different server (during development using react's own development server, and during production using Nginx).

Comment: So what you are saying is that you run the frontend app and the django project separately so you don't have any static files held within django? You therefore handle routing and all serving in the frontend and when you need to make an API call you just make a call to the server running the Django project?  Meaning the only routing in Django is for the API calls?

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty much it.

Comment: Thank you! I set up the rest api with a single resource just for testing however now I get the following: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Did you have this problem as well?  I added the necessary settings to the settings.py file however this is still present.

Comment: Ah, yes, you need to setup CORS headers. You'll need to create a middleware to return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header along with some other headers necessary for CORS. I wrote a detailed answer about this a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56832361/1925257

Comment: Thank you very much I'll check it out.

Comment: This worked fine thank you.